# Unable to open debugger port through IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jar, remote-debugging

I've got a server running on DigitalOcean and a JAR file that I want to debug. I first start the JAR on the remote server using

```
java -jar Server.jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

but on the console I see no output like "listening on port 5005...".

When I press debug in IntelliJ it says

> unable to open debugger port (198.xxx.xxx.xx:5005):
>   java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused"

This is my IntelliJ configuration:
[image]

I also tried using `-Xdebug` but it still didn't work.

If I set `suspend=y` it should wait until a debugger is connected, but instead, it starts without problems.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The command to start the remote Java process in debug mode looks correct. If you don't see "Listening to Port blah" when you start the server JAR, then it might mean that the debug args are not being picked up. Another way to quickly check this would be to test with a `telnet localhost 5005` on the machine where the server JAR is being executed. The `telnet` will fail if that port is not being used.

I suggest that you try the following, since the order of the parameters might be significant (I'll add some official evidence for this later):

```
java "agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005" -jar Server.jar
```

Comment: I would just like to stress out the fact that the order of the parameters *does* matter.

Comment: Where is the official evidence? Huh? HUH? Joke.

Answer (score 18):

this command worked for me:

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:5005'
```

by default idea remote dialog suggest:

```
'agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005'
```

change it to:

```
'agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:5005'
```

and issues port 5005.

Comment: It worked for me, but I don't know why... Problem was with intellij connecting to tomcat inside docker container.

Comment: While connecting to remote server from Intellij IDEA, when I used export JAVA_OPTS='-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5505'
it didn't work. But when I used address=0.0.0.0:5505 then it worked.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you. I spent last hour trying different configurations and all I was missing was "0.0.0.0" part before port

Comment: This in setenv '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:5505' work for me

Comment: Adding "0.0.0.0:" makes it work! Thanks! But what's the difference did "0.0.0.0:" make?

Comment: Also, the JDK version in use does matter. Notice the "Command line arguments for remote JVM" part in the middle Remote JVM Debug run config dialog windows? On the right side, there's a dropdown for different versions of JDK. Different versions of JDK require different JVM arguments on the server side.

Answer (score 5):

This command worked for me:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar Server.jar
```

Comment: pretty old thread but want to highlight one thing - I was using same command but had address=*:5005, I changed it to address=5005 and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to suifengpiao14 but I'm going to describe the problem a bit more in detail.

I checked multiple things, and at the end found the reason: actually as like as a restful service we want to be accessible from out of the server we are running it that we should set 0.0.0.0 as the nameserver, here we should do a similar one.
I checked the difference between the server from which I can remotely debug and the one which I can't. using *netstat* command:

for the server which I was ok with:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8323/java
```

for the server which I had problem with:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8323/java
```

So, using below jvm options should be helpful:

```
'agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005'
'agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:5005'
```

Answer (score 1):

When running debugger port in tomcat, you should start the tomcat server with this command:

```
catalina.bat jpda start
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because under settings -> build, execution, deployment -> debugger I had a built in server running on the same port as which I was trying to attach my debugger to for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who sometimes forget to read...

`Copy and paste the arguments to the command line when JVM is started`
says the Run/Debug Configuration in IntelliJ, directly under:
`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005`

**Means:**
Copy this line and go to your docker configuration. Add an environment variable (modify options dropdown). Paste it there with `JAVA_OPTS=` prepended.

Now when you did every correctly, you will have 
`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005` 
and 
`Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005`

This is who I solved it...

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced similar issue:

```
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused (Connection refused)"
```

I had it while running debugger w/ command line arguments for remote `JVM` using `Run/Debug` configurations:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
```

by [attaching IDE](https://medium.com/ocp-digital-factory/enable-remote-debugging-spring-boot-apps-on-kubernetes-e300be064477) with exposed debug agent server.

Since I've used `Kubernetes` cluster, the **reason** was:

[once the pod has been created and was running as expected](https://www.containiq.com/post/kubectl-port-forward), I needed to proceed to set up port forwarding with the `kubectl port-forward` command, with the port to expose locally for traffic from the application **before running debugger**.

Based on [kubectl port-forward syntax](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/kubectl-port-forward/):

```
kubectl port-forward <resource-type/resource-name> [local_port]:<pod_port>
```

In [format](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands) like:

```
kubectl port-forward <pod-name> -n <namespace> 5005:5005
```

or in a shorter form:

```
kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 5005:5005
```

> The client listens on port 5000 locally and forwards to 5000 in the
> pod.

Accordingly `entrypoint.sh` file of the service was configured w/ the following command for `Kubernetes` cluster:

```
java -Djava.security.egd.=file:/dev/./urandom -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 -Xmx400m -jar /service.jar
```

As result, running `port-forward` before debugger solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason is that the port is not enabled. You can try by enabling the port using the below command

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8001/tcp
```

Once the port is up, restart tomcat & try connecting again.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone That port in JVM debug is not your web app port

Answer (score 0):

this solved it for me:

```
net stop winnat

net start winnat
```

[IntelliJ IDEA - Address localhost:1099 is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986910/intellij-idea-address-localhost1099-is-already-in-use/73048297#73048297)

Answer (score 0):

Remote debugger needs to connect to the JVM that is already running in debug mode. Make sure you start the app you want to debug first with the JVM options suggested by the IDE. Then start Remote configuration to connect and debug this app.  ~CrazyCoder