# Tomcat Debug Error: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:63199): java.net.BindException "Address already in use: NET_Bind"

Tags: debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, port, netstat

I woke up for work and started receiving this error, but I can't find this specific error anywhere.

I tried using netstat -ano to find any instances running on the aformentioned port, and also the ports I run Tomcat on:

HTTP port: 8090
JMX port: 1099

But no processes are running on any of the three ports. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the 63199 port? Try restarting the PC. Check also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind) for solutions.

Comment: @Andrey I have looked for the port via netstat. I followed you link and took the TCPView software from the top of the list and none of the ports listed in my post appear on this list.

Comment: I can't seem to find a stack trace of this exception in the Jetbrain Directory or the Intellij Directory. How can I find a more comprehensive read out of this issue?

Comment: if you have installed any anti-virus, disable it and try once. -https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014469562

Answer (score 22):

Oh,my! This helps me a lot

```
// run cmd as administator
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

Before,I have tried this,but it doesn't work

```
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh winsock reset
```

Comment: I did not closed my IDEA and it worked.

Comment: Worked on IDEA 2021.3.3 and tomcat 9 debugging

Comment: It usually is not necessary to close your intelij. Still a great solution

Comment: thanks,I have updated my answer. delete the step : `restart your ide`

Answer (score 8):

As for me,the problem begin when i use idea to debug my web application.
Then i find where the port configured and change to another port.

[image: intellij tomcat debug]

Comment: This works for me. Just change the port number. E.g. to 59072.

Answer (score 3):

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986910/intellij-idea-address-localhost1099-is-already-in-use) might be helpful

> net stop winnat

> launch your idea tomcat

> net start winnat